# Partial fractions on complex function for Laurent series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions, laurent-series

Whats the proper way to calculate the partial fractions for functions like these

$$  f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2(z+1)} \\
f(z)=\frac{z}{(2-z)^3z}
$$

before calculating the Laurent series?

Comment: For starters, just cancel out the “z” factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac z{z^2(z+1)}=\frac1{z(z+1)}=\frac1z-\frac1{z+1}\;--\text{almost no need for calculations: just good "eye"}$$

$$\frac z{(2-z)^3z}=-\frac1{(z-2)^3}\;,\;\text{and this is even more boring than the first one...}$$